# Object Name: bad value for restricted picklist field in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I received the below error , when i tried to create a new action through Buttons/Links section in object manager in lightning. This error popped up when i clicked the New action button. It did not even go to the page which asks for the name , label of button etc

> Validation Errors While Saving Record(s) There were custom validation
>   error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first
>   validation error encountered was "Object Name: bad value for
>   restricted picklist field: SocialPost".
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: The message explains your problem: your UI logic is allowing an invalid value to be specified for the `SocialPost` picklist field (that is setup to only allow specific values).

Comment: Hi Keith.. I received this error when i tried to create new action by clicking the New action button. This error popped up when i just clicked the New Action button..

Comment: OK that is weird - best emphasise that in your question.

Comment: Is the button overridden by a custom lightning component?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bug related to Lightning Experience. You can use classic UI, it should work there. I had also faced the same issue.